# temporary failure in name resolution when using multiprocess with wsl

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04, openmpi

## issue:

when running this example code:

code example to reproduce

```
import requests


def worker(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.status_code


def run_workers_for_lst(url_lst: list):
    with mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker, url_lst)
    return dict(zip(url_lst, results))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url_lst = [
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=1",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=3",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=4",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=5",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=6",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=7",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=8",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=9",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=10",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=11",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=12",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=13",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=14",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=15",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=16",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=17",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=18",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=19",
        "https://www.ahuzot.co.il/Parking/ParkingDetails/?ID=20",
    ]
    print(run_workers_for_lst(url_lst=url_lst))
```

it seems that there is a problem then running multiprocess, cause when I run this, I am getting "temporary failure in name resolution"

[vscode fail code on "temporary failure in name resolution" error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leiCU.png)

### other information:

###openmpi

from looking in the web, it seems like there is a relation between the DNS name resolution to openmpi package installed in linux apt packages, so I am adding info related to openmpi as well, although my DNS resolution when running `ping google.com` works just fine.

```
$ apt list --installed | grep openmpi:

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libcaf-openmpi-3/focal,now 2.8.0-1 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
libcoarrays-openmpi-dev/focal,now 2.8.0-1 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
libopenmpi3/focal,now 4.0.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openmpi-bin/focal,now 4.0.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
openmpi-common/focal,now 4.0.3-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
```

#### env info

- Python 3.8.10
- vscode 1.69.0
- Ubuntu 20.04
- WSL1
- Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.2006]
- Linux version 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft (Microsoft@Microsoft.com) (gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC) )

just to state out loud for issue documentation, DNS should not fail, and that's the issue I am looking to solve here.

any help on that matter would help.

thank you.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue.,

Comment: Hey @Alexander, First, thx for the super fast response. regarding the issue, can you please try again with `url_lst` length 5x times longer, or even 20x, I see it won't happen with a small number of items, only after a certain number of items... (e.g. it won't reproduce with 5 items in my machine too, only with 11+) Any ideas maybe to help me move forward with solving this? perhaps I can supply more information?

Comment: I am still unable to reproduce but I am using python 3.10 everything else is the same

Comment: @Alexander in that case I think I will let a couple of contributers try to reproduce it. if they fail as well, I guess I will close the question...

Comment: the issue disappeared, thx @Alexander for the help.